# Connecting to Google Game Service for Android

Tags: android

I've been scratching my head for a few days and I hope someone can help me out. I'm trying to implement leaderboards in my game and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong! When my game starts up, I see the "Connecting to Google Play Games" screen load up and then I'm able click the "sign in" button.

After that I get a message saying "Unknown issue with Google Play Service". I went through the documentation and a few tutorials but still can't figure out what is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameInterface, GameHelper.GameHelperListener {

    protected RelativeLayout layout;
    protected GameHelper gameHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
        gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true, "GameHelper");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

         // Create the layout
        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        // Create the libgdx View
        View gameView = initializeForView(new BirdBlast(this), config);

        layout.addView(gameView);

        gameHelper.setup(this);

        // Hook it all up
        setContentView(layout);

        if(!gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
        gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        System.out.println("TEST: " + gameHelper.isSignedIn());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        System.out.println("TEST: " + gameHelper.isSignedIn());
    }
}
```

Here is my logcat output:

```
07-14 19:19:43.920  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=RC_RESOLVE, resp=RESULT_OK
07-14 19:19:43.920  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: onAR: Resolution was RESULT_OK, so connecting current client again.
07-14 19:19:43.920  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: Starting connection.
07-14 19:19:44.871  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: onConnectionFailed
07-14 19:19:44.871  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: Connection failure:
07-14 19:19:44.871  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper:    - code: INTERNAL_ERROR(8)
07-14 19:19:44.871  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper:    - resolvable: false
07-14 19:19:44.871  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper:    - details: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}
07-14 19:19:44.871  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: WILL resolve because user initiated sign-in.
07-14 19:19:44.871  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: resolving problem...
07-14 19:19:44.871  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}
07-14 19:19:44.871  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: result has no resolution. Giving up.
07-14 19:19:44.871  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame W/GameHelper﹕ disconnect() called when client was already disconnected.
07-14 19:19:44.911  25791-25791/com.mypackage.mygame D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: Notifying LISTENER of sign-in FAILURE (error)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem yesterday.
Every time you run your app try clearing the google play service cache.
Also look at complete logs and see if you are getting any 403 error from google play.
If that's the case than you may need to enable more API's from google developer console